# Deploy python app without any web server/ framework to azure app service linux

Tags: python, azure, github-actions

I have a custom Linux app where I am not using any framework. It is a simple app with some module which does some scheduled job.
to run on local , i am using `python main.py arg1 arg2`. That's it it will use `schedule` package and schedule jobs. I do have `requirements.txt`.

Now I want to deploy this to Azure. Service I got the Azure WebApp linux. I know this is not the correct service since I am not serving anything over http, I am just connecting some db, APIs etc.

When I trying to deply using github action, I am getting issue with virtual environment, etc.

E.g. If I simply deploy with start up command, I am getting error

```
2023-11-11T15:19:27.054568534Z Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite -userStartupCommand 'python main.py dev s'
2023-11-11T15:19:27.193901315Z Found build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'. Deserializing it...
2023-11-11T15:19:27.214165170Z Build Operation ID: 7f870c51d6df2456
2023-11-11T15:19:27.231953721Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20230707.1, Commit: 0bd28e69919b5e8beba451e8677e3345f0be8361, ReleaseTagName: 20230707.1
2023-11-11T15:19:27.243554311Z Output is compressed. Extracting it...
2023-11-11T15:19:27.243579812Z Extracting '/home/site/wwwroot/output.tar.gz' to directory '/tmp/8dbe2c7322f355e'...
2023-11-11T15:19:30.560170296Z App path is set to '/tmp/8dbe2c7322f355e'
2023-11-11T15:19:36.581666909Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2023-11-11T15:19:36.805404566Z Using packages from virtual environment antenv located at /tmp/8dbe2c7322f355e/antenv.
2023-11-11T15:19:36.805441267Z Updated PYTHONPATH to '/opt/startup/app_logs:/tmp/8dbe2c7322f355e/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages'
2023-11-11T15:19:39.130548772Z ERROR:root:Critical Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/8dbe2c7322f355e/config/config.json'
```

Here is my github action

```
  - name: azure webapp deploy
    uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
    with:
      app-name: ${{ vars.APP_NAME }}
      package: ${{ vars.DEPLOY_PATH }}
      startup-command: 'python main.py dev s'
```

Comment: The Azure backend system tried to handle the things you uploaded as typical Python based web apps and failed. You might switch to virtual machines or containers.

Comment: @LexLi So no solution to run this on azure app service?

Answer (score 0):

If your web app code is not serving any **HTTP request** then it will fail in Azure Web App. What you can do is create an **Azure Timer Trigger Function** and add your schedule code in the **Timer trigger** with your schedule based on the CRON expression, So the Timer Function will be Triggered in that particular scheduled CRON time. You can also, Deploy the Timer Trigger in the Function app via Github actions like below.

You can make use of basic Azure Function Consumption based app which won't cost you much.

Create **Timer Trigger** by referring to this [**MS Document1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v1,isolated-process,nodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-python) and [**MSDocument2**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal)

In your **Timer Trigger** **`init.py`** add your schedule by defining it as a method, My init.py code below prints one sentence when the timer trigger is triggered.  **`call_your_task_function()`** is my task that prints a statement you can use your logic here.

```py
import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)

    # Insert your task or function to be executed on schedule here
    # For example, you could call your script or function:
    call_your_task_function()

def call_your_task_function():
    # Your task logic goes here
    logging.info('This is a basic task running on a schedule!')
```

*My function.json with CRON schedule that runs my Function every 1 minute you can schedule this as per  your requirement*

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

I uploaded this Function in [My github repository](https://github.com/sid24desai/TimerTrigger) and deployed it to Azure Function app like below:-

You can clone my repository as a reference.

***In your Azure Function App > Visit > Deployment Center > Source - Github > Repository - TimerTrigger > Branch - main > Save***

[image]

After you click on Save the Github Action workflow will start deploying the Function like below:-

**Github Action workflow:-**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - valleyfunc90

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' 
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.10' 

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip     
        
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: 'valleyfunc90'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_D2480FC837C6428D938011D883C5E562 }}
```

[image]

[image]

One more method, If you want to use Azure Web app, You can use streamlit package and add streamlit in your main.py code to run your task by serving a streamlit page, One sample Http page will be available and your task will run in the backend. You can also add button to run your task in main.py itself. Refer below:-

For streamlit app to work its mandatory to deploy your web app with **Pricing plan - B1 and Python version 3.10**:-

[image]

**main.py:-**

```py
import streamlit as st

def calculate_sum(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2

def main():
    st.title('Simple Calculator')

    # Define arguments
    arg1 = 5
    arg2 = 10

    # Calculate sum
    result = calculate_sum(arg1, arg2)

    # Display result
    st.write(f"The sum of {arg1} and {arg2} is {result}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**requirements.txt:-**

```
streamlit
```

After Deployment add below startup command in your web app:-

```py
python -m streamlit run main.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0
```

[image]

**Output after deployment and adding startup command:-**

[image]

I also agree with Lex Li, Azure web app will require something to serve in the Https request and a startup command to initialize the app. Streamlit makes it easier for you to run your tasks and serves a basic website for you without a need for any HTML, CSS or routes.

As alternative **you can also make use of Azure VM** with as low size as B1s to run your task which is a Free size available in Azure or **Azure Container apps** or **[Azure Webjobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)** to run the tasks in background with your existing Web App or [**Azure batch service**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-python) to run long running tasks.